# If i was to create a website for someone and it included(s) a php page(s) would they have to have php configured aswell?

Tags: php

Some one want's me to create a website for them and it inclueds a shopping trolley system which i will probably do in php... would they have to have php to publish the website?

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: does it rain from clouds? (same type of question...)

Comment: @Sam - what the frak is a 'webspace' does this webspace have php, if not than no, no it will not work.

Comment: please dont make a trolley (or rather cart) system . it will be more bugged than sonys firmwares

Comment: Sam, no offence but if you have to ask this question, pass the job onto someone else

Comment: @Keith, if the hiring party doesn't make the appropriate checks to determine weather their developer can do the job I don't feel bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They will need PHP running on there server / machine they run it from yes.

You will need to check if there current hosting provider supports PHP and if they do make sure they support the version you are using.

If your not sure you need to contact your clients hosting provider and ask them the question.

Comment: but they will be using web space instead of their own webserver.

Comment: Then their server must have PHP installed and running. It is free so wouldn't think this would be an issue, check with them :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course. The webserver where the site will be published must have PHP installed, otherwise the PHP pages will not work!

Comment: No matter if the server is physically in their office or if they rented some webspace...PHP must be installed!

Answer (score 1):

it wouldnt be necessary to have PHP configured.
just installed.

the default configuration will work as well